# Can a variable be declared in java using class name only?

Tags: java, oop, variables, linked-list, inner-classes

Can a variable be declared in java using the name of a subclass? I found this piece of code about linked lists very confusing. See, how the head of the list has been declared. Can someone please explain?

```
class LinkedList
{
    Node head;  // head of list

    /* Linked list Node*/
    class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;

        // Constructor to create a new node
        // Next is by default initialized
        // as null
        Node(int d)
           {
               data = d;
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not a subclass but an inner class.

Comment: What is confusing ?

Comment: You can declare a reference to be of any accessible type. That's all that's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an object can indeed contain a reference to another object of the same type as an instance member.

For example, this is the standard class definition of a Linked List Node:

```
class Node {
    int value;
    Node next;
    ... // instance methods follow
}
```

You have the current node which must point to a reference of the next node in the linked list.

Comment: object? No object has been invoked as yet.

Comment: @AsmaRahimAliJafri Right, should've provided an example for that. My bad, and thanks.